# Universal PNG fix script?

Tags: javascript, png, iepngfix

Does anyone know of a universal, one stop PNGFix script that isn't dependent on a specific library (like jQuery or Prototype?).

I just want to drop it in the header and have it take care of all transparent .png's from my stylesheets and markup.

Can't seem to find one that will do the job.

Comment: Just to warn you, this kind of fix can do several hurts to your site for users running IE6, including but not limited to making links under which there's a transparent PNG unclickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to use this at my company, until we finally moved off of IE6:
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/.  Just google "png fix" or "IE6 png fix" and you'll find dozens of resources.  But as others have already warned, many of these cause more problems than they solve, and individual fixes are usually in order.

The best solution would be to not support IE6.  Start lobbying with your company's IT department.

Answer (score 1):

A non-library dependent one would be http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

However you have to individually point out which elements should be targeted. There is never going to be a script that will fix every single png properly because there are so many position/layout scenarios and bugs relating to stacking order in IE6 that it's impossible to account for every situation which is why it's best to individually fix elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to ie png fix. [Unit Png fix](http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php)

this is best compare than [Helix Png Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/)