# animate opacity png fix

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is ther a fix for the animate opacity in jQuery I've tried supersleight and many others but I get no results. The image loads fine as a png it's just when it is animated i get problems. I have also tried EpngFix  iepngfix and DD_belatedPNG but they don't work. Im using ie8 on windows 7

Comment: Refer [here][1] [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160857/universal-png-fix-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ie8 and ie6 you can use

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="test.png")
  alpha(opacity=50);
background: none;
```

jquery animate opacity will work perfectly because it simply changes filter: alpha

for ie7 see
[ie7 png opacity. is it possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277085/ie7-png-opacity-is-it-possible)