# ie7 png opacity. is it possible

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

1) dont use ie8 with option "work as ie7". it lies in this case
2) use clean ie7 or ietester last version

For example test.png can be 50% tranparency jpeg picture.
I know 2 methods to use it in ie7:

```
background-image: "test.png"; filter: alpha(opacity=70)
```

you will see **gray** image

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="test.png")
  alpha(opacity=70);
background: none;
```

you will see **white** image

2 variant came to us from ie6!

example: http://pastehtml.com/view/awfp66p2m.html
1 original.
2 grey background.
3 white progid

**ie7** screenshot: http://clip2net.com/clip/m46295/1307529587-cliptj2620-2kb.png

**ie6** screenshot: http://clip2net.com/clip/m46295/1307529630-cliptt2620-2kb.png

3 image works perfectly in ie6 and ie8. it means in ie6 and ie8 i can animate opacity using jquery!

Comment: I don't even know what you're talking about. IE7's rendering engine doesn't use DirectX.

Comment: okey. in this case i am wrong

Comment: Please revise this to clearly state your question, currently it's a bit ambiguous unless read several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I *think* this is a known bug in *all* versions of IE (at least up to 8, not sure about 9): Images with alpha transparency will not show correctly if the element containing them has an `opacity` value different from 100%.

See this answer for more details: [How to make a Google Maps semi-transparent PNG tile layer work in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020690/how-to-make-a-google-maps-semi-transparent-png-tile-layer-work-in-ie8)

Comment: yes it is but. i have **no parent element** with transparency at all. 2 variant works perfectly in ie6 but not in ie7!

Comment: @puchu ah, okay! Can you post the relevant HTML so that becomes clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this one to be pretty helpful: http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php